# Transforming a Numeric variable into a Factor in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My results data are categorized by whether the experiment they came from had 8 test groups or 16 test groups:

```
set.seed(123)
results <- runif(10)
size <- c(16, 16, 16, 8, 16, 8, 8, 16, 16, 8)
df <- data.frame(results, size)
```

I want `size` to be a factor variable. In base R I would do this simply:

```
df$size <- as.factor(df$size)
```

My question is, how do you do the same in dplyr? I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  do(as_factor(size))
```

But I received the error `no applicable method for 'as_factor' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
   mutate(size = factor(size))

str(df)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ results: num  0.288 0.788 0.409 0.883 0.94 ...    
# $ size   : Factor w/ 2 levels "8","16": 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why do() even exists. I feel like every time do() fails, the answer is just "use mutate instead"

Comment: @mmyoung77  I would prefer not to use `do`, but there are certain cases, where you create a model say `lm` or others, `mutate` may not be able to work in those cases unless you enclose it in a `list`.  Besides, `do` is slower compared to `mutate`

Comment: @mmyoung77  Because you asked for a clarification, here is one  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604584/including-dplyr-in-the-function/52615275#52615275) where `do` can be used (though, it can be done with `map` as well

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(size = as_factor(as.character(size)))
```

Once the variable has been converted to a character then the as_factor() call works.

Edit: The solution above is even better!

```
df %>% mutate(size = factor(size))
```